# How create a query that count id_libro if my entity contains the object Libro

Tags: java, jpa

Class definition:

```
public class Noleggio {
@NotNull
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_libro")
private Libro libro;
```

my query, but doesn't work

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Noleggio n WHERE n.idLibro=?1")
Integer countById(Long idLibro);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's JPQL not SQL so you cannot us *. You have to use the alias and the return type is Long not Integer.

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(n) FROM Noleggio n WHERE n.idLibro=?1")
Long countByNoleggioIdLibro(Long idLibro);
```

Or you event don't need the @Query annotation:

```
Long countByLibroId(Long idLibro);
```

This will create the query by naming convention.

Read mor about the query generation:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.lang.Long com.finance.biblioteca.repository.NoleggioRepository.countById(java.lang.Long)!

Comment: There is a name clash. I changed my answer.